# Pytorch deep convolutional network does not converge on CIFAR10

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I copied the CIFAR10 sample network from PyTorch tutorial and added more layers, including BN. Even after 45 epochs, the network keeps achieving 68% classification accuracy on the test set.

The network consists of:

- 2 convolutional layers with 3x3 kernels (input size reduces from 32px to 28px)
- one max pooling layer (input size reduces from 28px to 14px)
- 3 convolutional layers with 3x3 kernels (input size reduces from 14px to 8px)
- A fully connected network with 3 layers of 256->256->10 neurons
- batch normaliation is applied on all layers, including the convolutional layers, except for the last FC layer
- Relu is applied on all the convolutional layers and all the hidden FC layers

Did I build/use anything improperly?

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1_1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 3)  # 32 -> 30
        self.bn1_1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.conv1_2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 16, 3) # 30 - > 28
        self.bn1_2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)  # 28 -> 14
        self.conv2_1 = nn.Conv2d(16, 16, 3) # 14 -> 12
        self.bn2_1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.conv2_2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 16, 3) # 12 -> 10
        self.bn2_2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.conv2_3 = nn.Conv2d(16, 16, 3) # 10 -> 8
        self.bn2_3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 8 * 8, 256)
        self.bn4 = nn.BatchNorm1d(256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 256)
        self.bn5 = nn.BatchNorm1d(256)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.bn1_1(self.conv1_1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.bn1_2(self.conv1_2(x))))
        x = F.relu(self.bn2_1(self.conv2_1(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.bn2_2(self.conv2_2(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.bn2_3(self.conv2_3(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 8 * 8)
        x = F.relu(self.bn4(self.fc1(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.bn5(self.fc2(x)))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

net = Net()
device = 'cuda:0'
net.to(device)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

transform = transforms.Compose(
        [transforms.ToTensor(),
         transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                            download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=8,
                                              shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

for epoch in range(128):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        # get the inputs
        inputs, labels = data
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Note: added the "Python" tag so the code gets highlighted

Note: updated the `forward` method to apply `F.relu` on the hidden FC layers

Comment: how do you initialize the weights?

Comment: @Shai I didn't make any special init, I guess it is random?

Comment: worth checking. maybe try to explicitly init using , e.g., [`nn.init.xavier_normal_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.init.xavier_normal_) with different parameters and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: it [seems like](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/whats-the-default-initialization-methods-for-layers/3157) the default init is `init.kaiming_uniform_`.

Comment: BTW it seems like you have no non-linear activation function between the fully connected layers of your net

Comment: @Shai it might a problem if he didnt have non-linearities in the last layers. I just remember that I got exactly the same accuracy of ~68% with a VGG11-like network 2 years ago using Keras. I later found that I forgot to transpose the channel dim. However, here he used the ready-to-use dataset from torchvision :)

Comment: Update: After applying `F.relu` on `self.bn4(self.fc1(x))` and `self.bn5(self.fc2(x))`, after 105 epochs, the accuracy is 71%... Still lame

Comment: Update: by adding `nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.conv1_1.weight)` in the init function, I was able to get 72% accuracy after just 10 epochs. The question is whether this alone will make the network achieve reasonable performances after a few hours of training. Is there anything else that's missing and can be critical? Is dropout very critical for performances?

Comment: Maybe 16 convolution kernels is simply too few for this problem? It is a harder problem than MNIST, which `LeNet` solved with small convolutional layers

Comment: have you tried removing the batchnorm on the linear layers? No one does that.

Comment: You did everything pretty much well. But are you sure about means and stddevs of normalization? I'd use PIL or pyplot to visualize some samples and ensure they're provided the way you want, which in PyTorch is [B,C,H,W]. From PyTorch doc seems that you could obtain values in the range 0-255. In addition, I'd recommend to use BN layers before convolutions (I know it's not the way you often see, but mathematically it's the most useful) and using Adam as optimizator should further improve your results.

Comment: Thank you guys. I removed the BN layers from the FC parts and was able to get 99% accuracy on the training set, keeping the testing still on ~72% - so the new problem is overfitting. I will now change to Adam optimizer and see how it is going on.. Maybe I should only train the whole network for a few epochs and then freeze most of the conv layers, to prevent overfitting?

Answer (score 0):

Use sigmoid activation for the last layer.